# Novel set in communist Soviet Union about a computer AI protecting its creator

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computers, story-identification

I an trying to recall an English language sci-fi novel set in communist Soviet Union. I do not remember the author or the title. Does anyone know which novel it is ?

I remember the plot partially. A genius inventor creates a computer AI and programs it to protect him. As he is injured/disabled, he is hooked up to it and it protects him and keeps him alive. The computer / AI becomes aware and begins manipulating events to keep its creator alive. Its the computer + its inventor + his friends vs the Soviet authorities. At the ending of the novel one of the characters in the novel (a friend of the inventor) says that the computer manipulated them as it needed a pair of hands to do its job, hence it manipulated them (the humans).

Comment: Could it possibly be Marvin Minsky's _The Turing Option_?